# How to custom code the Elementor Loop item?

Tags: customization, custom-field

I have an Elementor Pro and ACF on my site. I have a custom post type with a custom field called document.

I want to be able to conditionally render the "Download" button with the document link if that custom field was filled.

I do not see a way to do it in the Loop builder, so I am wondering if it's possible to hand code this loop item? Or is there another way to do this?

I want to refrain from installing another plugin to do this if possible